# Character rotation according to camera causes rapid flipping when game starts

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, transformation

When I load my scene, my character rotates +90 and -90 on the X axis very fast about 4 or 5 times, and then he stops at -90 on X axis (lays back down).

When I move the character, the rotations are just the way I want them, but I need to fix that weird bug at the beginning of the game.

Here's my character's movement logic. It's based on the rotation of the camera, which is a child of my character object.

```
void Update() {
    Vector2 vec = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
    vec = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(vec, 1);

    Vector3 camF = cam.transform.forward;
    Vector3 camR = cam.transform.right;

    camF.y = 0;
    camR.y = 0;
    camF = camF.normalized;
    camR = camR.normalized;

    transform.position += (camF * vec.y + camR * vec.x) * Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed;

    Vector3 deltaPosition = transform.position - prevPosition;

    if (deltaPosition != Vector3.zero)
    {
        transform.forward = deltaPosition;
    }

    prevPosition = transform.position;
}
```

[image: Scene]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "camera is child object of my character"

Yup, there's your problem. Let's walk through what happens:

1. We use the camera's forward to compute a new position for the character
2. We use the new position to compute a new forward direction for the character
3. The camera is a child of the character, so rotating the character changes the camera's forward
4. But back in point 1, our calculation was based on the camera's forward!

   So now the next time we do that calculation, with a different forward, we get a different result...
5. ...which computes a different forward direction for the character
6. ...which changes the forward direction of the camera...

...so on and so on in a feedback loop, which creates the flickering rotation that you observe.

So, easy fix: **don't make your camera a child of the character** if you intend to use the camera to set the character's rotation. This avoids unintended feedback between the two sets of transformation logic.

You'll also want to ensure that your `prevPosition` is initialized and your `horizontal` and `vertical` inputs are populated correctly (we can't see that part of your code - don't hide so much from us if you want deep & useful help!), and you may also want to add a larger tolerance on the `if (deltaPosition != Vector3.zero)` line - possibly comparing `deltaPosition.sqrMagnitude > 0.1 * Time.deltaTime * Time.deltaTime` or somesuch.

Comment: I did not understand why did you want me to wrote `Time.deltaTime` two times. But i did what exactly what you asked me to do, it works better but now character just stays -90 on x axis, but not flipping.

Comment: We multiply by `deltaTime` twice because `deltaPosition` already includes `deltaTime`, and we're taking its `sqrMagnitude`, which squares the `deltaTime` inside it. It sounds like you might want to calculate your rotation differently, since you're moving on the xy plane, but `forward` points along the local z axis.

Comment: So how can i do that?

Comment: Hard to say, since I've never seen your character or how it's supposed to be oriented in your world. Try editing your question to include a screenshot showing 3 things: 1) your character in your scene, 2) the local translation gizmo drawn on that character, so we can see which way its local axes point relative to its visuals, 3) the scene compass in the corner of the window, so we can compare this local orientation against the world coordinate axes.

Comment: I've added the screenshot

Comment: Hm, I'm not able to reproduce the bug you describe when I build a similar setup on my machine. You're sure [you have your gizmo in local mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html), and you initialize your `previousPosition` before update runs?

Comment: I have `prevPosition = transform.position;` in void Awake, and yes my gizmo is in local mode

Comment: Then you may need to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example of this issue in a new, empty project, and post it as a new Question.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/newbam that's the bug, incase you visualize it wrong. And i need to say i change my camera's transform after this codes, may it be the wrong part?

Comment: Again, I can't tell you that, because you've chosen to show us so little of your project, we're unable to reproduce the problem with the parts you've shown.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/newdwz that's the only code that's related to camera

Comment: Omg, i can't believe this bug is happening 'cause of that kind of idiotic thing. I've changed my character position (on y axis) to 0, apperantly my character lays down just 'cause of the falling down. Thank you so much for your effort, and so sorry for bothering you for this stupidness :D